# WordPress not connecting to database in file with multiple MySQL connections

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, pdo

I have one external WordPress file where I'm trying to connect to my WordPress database and another database that's not WordPress all in that one file.

Here's the code in that file:

```
include('/var/www/html/wp-load.php'); // WP connection

define ("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define ("DB_USER", "mysqluser");
define ("DB_PASS",'password123');
define ("DB_NAME","jobs");
try {
    $dsn = "mysql:dbname=".DB_NAME.";host=".DB_HOST;
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    return $dbh;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Here is the error I get for connecting to the WordPress database:

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'wordpress'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If the file is within wordpress then you can use global variable $wpdb to run queries. also i think now php supports mysqli extension..... 1 more thing is try to change localhost with define ('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');

Comment: So the error says the user 'wordpress' is trying to connect to the localhost.  The code you posted has a different user in it.  If you are trying to redefine with define something that has already been set you should be seeing warnings and if you are not you should turn up your error logging.  Try using variables instead of constants.

Comment: @RyanH The user `wordpress` is connecting in the first line. The rest of the code is the 2nd database connection with another user

Comment: @ShaikhAejazAhmed I tried to change it to `127.0.01` but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it! It looks like `define ("DB_HOST")...` native WP was already using it so I changed it to something else.